# Why after fresh Ubuntu 12.04 installation update aren't being installed?

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, software-installation

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a computer. Everything is fine without update. Just after the installation, it was showing about 200 MB updates to download. Since then I'm trying to install all the updates. Now it's partially completed, some of the software (firefox,VLC) is updated. Still it's showing 39.3 MB updates to download and it's failing again and again. Every time I tried to install these 39.3 MB updates, it shows that, it can't connect to internet, but there is no problem with my connection (Network indicator shows it's connected and I can browse and download anything). It's giving me the following message:

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic-pae_3.2.0-43.68_i386.deb Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.2.0-43-generic-pae_3.2.0-43.68_i386.deb Size mismatch
```

I thought this is a problem with sources list. So I've given the following command

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
```

Previously, I've faced similar type of problem with a different computer. At that time, this solution worked for me, but now I'm still facing this problem. Anyone please help me to solve this problem.

### Update

Here is the output of `sudo apt-get update`

```
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [72 B]                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                               
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]           
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US             
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [383 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [383 kB]       
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [5,467 B]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [87.1 kB]  
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [87.1 kB]  
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [87.1 kB] 
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [6,582 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [625 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [10.0 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [203 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.8 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.8 kB]
100% [16 Packages bzip2 0 B] [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14
bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
    perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
    Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Fetched 935 kB in 3min 39s (4,261 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the lists? `sudo apt-get update` should get you the current package indexes...

Comment: If you are working in an organization then check for a firewall FTP block.
If the FTP port is blocked by the firewall then it won't allow you to update.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My problem is solved now. I'm posting here the solution step by step. From the output of `sudo apt-get update`, I was facing following problem:

```
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

To solve this problem I entered the following commands one by one.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then the output was

```
audity@auditypc:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
[sudo] password for audity: 
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release.gpg'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release.gpg'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release.gpg'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock'
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Is a directory
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_main_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_main_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_main_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_multiverse_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_multiverse_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_Release'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_Release.gpg'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_restricted_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_restricted_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_restricted_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Release.gpg'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_multiverse_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_multiverse_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_Release'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_Release.gpg'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_universe_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_multiverse_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_multiverse_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_Release'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_Release.gpg'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_restricted_source_Sources'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_universe_i18n_Index'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en'
removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_universe_source_Sources'
audity@auditypc:~$ sudo apt-get clean
[sudo] password for audity: 
audity@auditypc:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
audity@auditypc:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]                 
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Get:4 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [72 B]                      
Get:5 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]                 
Get:6 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [763 B]                   
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]         
Get:8 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release [11.9 kB]                       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Get:9 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release [7,078 B]                   
Get:10 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [8,130 B]                 
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B]      
Get:12 http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages [8,261 B]    
Get:13 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [10.8 kB]           
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]       
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US             
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]        
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]        
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                     
E: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2
audity@auditypc:~$
```

Now I was facing a GPG error. To solve this I tried the following

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get clean
# cd /var/lib/apt
# mv lists lists.old
# mkdir -p lists/partial
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
# exit
```

After this command. I entered the final commands.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 9):

Just had the US archive package list hash sum mismatch on some fresh 12.04.5 installs. Shorter solution that worked for me at least:

```
# rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_*
# rm /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise*
# aptitude update
... now worked ...
```